# DRF serializer - name 'self' is not defined

Tags: django-rest-framework

Here is my serializer -

```
class WidgetListSerializer(EncryptedLookupModelSerializer):

    owner = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='username',
        queryset=MyAppUser.objects.filter(user=self.context['request'].user),
        default = serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    parent = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='name',
        queryset=WidgetList.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model=WidgetList
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'owner', 'parent')
```

I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback:
File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  119.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  365.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  401.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/opt/myproject_app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  395.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/opt/myproject/myproject/urls.py" in <module>
  20. from gui import views
File "/opt/myproject/gui/views.py" in <module>
  20. from api.serializers import *
File "/opt/myproject/api/serializers.py" in <module>
  52. class WidgetListSerializer(EncryptedLookupModelSerializer):
File "/opt/myproject/api/serializers.py" in WidgetListSerializer
  56.         queryset=MyAppUser.objects.filter(user=self.context['request'].user),

Exception Type: NameError at /api/widgetlists/
Exception Value: name 'self' is not defined
```

I basically want the serializer to only return in the POST HTML the ability to show the current user instead of all Users which is currently does.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you can't use self inside a field definition (same as model's fields). Self is not define. If I understand it right you want to return the username of the current user.

```
class WidgetListSerializer(EncryptedLookupModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    ...

    def get_owner(self, obj):
        return self.context['request'].user.username
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that it removes the field from the POST option.  I still want to see the Parent options in the POST but I only want it to show the values that are owned by the user logged in.